# Deep Links Redirection error in iOS - "Safari cannot open the page"

Tags: ios, hyperlink, deep-linking, branch.io

This is sudip here, we've implemented branchio in our app and in website. We're facing an issue in ios 10.3, whenever we open link in ios 10.3 it shows error "safari cannot open the page, the address is invalid", and in background we have our banner which says get the app.

2. if we click on cancel on confirmation in safari during popup "Do you want to open this in app", it starts showing "safari cannot open the page, the address is invalid"

how can we resolve the above issue

**Product Category  Links Redirection**

**Settings for used in link settings of branch dashboard**

URI Scheme Deep Link Mode : Intelligent,

Enabled Universal & App Links for both iOS & Android,

**We've tested in:**

Android - Opened links from hangout, working smoothly

IPhone CE , iOS version 10.3.3 : Opened links from hangout, using safari browser, shows error "Safari cannot open the page"

IPhone SE , iOS version 10.3.3 : Opened links from hangout, using safari browser, shows error "Safari cannot open the page"

Link(s) for Testing
https://link.onference.in/ZsSH9R6uAU

Answer (score 1):

First step is please go to settings-> safari -> Clear History and website data and the check the link, if its not working then you need to check the settings in info.plist and Associated Domains

Answer (score 0):

This alerts usually happens for users who do not have the app on their device when we try to use the iOS URI scheme because the universal link for your app fails. To give better assistance, can you please validate if your universal link setting in your iOS app is correct by [our validation tool](https://docs.branch.io/pages/resources/validation-tools/#universal-link-validator) and give us your result? Also, you can find common issues that cause universal links to fail [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/universal-links/#common-issues-that-cause-universal-links-to-fail).

Please do reach out at integrations@branch.io if you have any further questions!